# I want to do a PhD in Quantum Computing. Which universities in English-speaking countries have prominent research groups in this field?

Tags: education

Most universities I checked have a Quantum Information group, and they usually mention the term "Quantum Computing" somewhere on their website, but it's not very clear how much research is actually done in Quantum Computing.

I would like to study at an institution where there are at least 2-3 potential supervisors who perform active research in Quantum Computing and are willing to take new students. (I plan to begin my PhD in the 2015/2016 academic year.)

Comment: One way to figure this out on your own would be to take the list of groups you've compiled and then search for their publications to see what it is they are actually doing.

Comment: This list question appears to be off-topic because it is about producing a list of educational institutions rather than asking an actual physics question. List questions tend to fit poorly into the SE Q&A format.